# Civicontribute radiobuttons without "none", where the "Other" contribution field deselects radiobuttons

Tags: civicontribute, javascript, jquery

This is a Theming/UI question for CiviCRM.

[image: 1]

I've done some theming to turn the radiobutton's into clickable options.

[image]

When I select an amount it updates the 'Regular Amount' field.

[image]

However, when I select other amount, the previous option stays selected and they are added together.

What jQuery/js can I use to make the 'Other Amount' field de-select/unset the contribution amount choice?

I've tried code like this but for the life of me I can not get it to deselect anything!

```
$( "#price_78" ).focus(function() {
$('#CIVICRM_QFID_408_2').prop('checked', false);
});
```

Can you help me come up with a viable solution? We do not want to use the 'None' field on the contribution amount. I tried SimpleDonate but it did not work well for our implementation. We want the focus of the 'Other Amount' field to deselect any contribution amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code worked for me:

```
CRM.$(function($) {
  $('input[type=text]', '#priceset').on('keyup', function() {
    if ($(this).val()) {
      $('input[type=radio]:checked', '#priceset').prop('checked', false).each(function() {
        calculateRadioLineItemValue(this);
      });
      calculateText(this);
    }
  });
  $('input[type=radio]', '#priceset').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('input[type=text]', '#priceset').val('').each(function() {
        calculateText(this);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Coleman, your code works, but it does not visually "deselect" the contribution amount radio button on my form. The price calculates correctly, however. Is this how you experience it?

Comment: I have no idea how you styled those buttons, so can't comment. It works on normal radio buttons.

Comment: You are right, it's my theme! Answer accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I have a contribution form layout similar to Coleman's that shows clickable amounts (pseudo-buttons) instead of visible radio buttons. It also has the "Other Amount" pseudo-button (see below).

In order to get the right behavior, I had to also trigger the `click()` event on the radio button for the "Other Amount". This then correctly updated all the visual styles. The javascript is below.

[image: contribution buttons and other amount input]

```
CRM.$(function($) {
  // check for "other amount" text input
  var inpTxt = $('input[type=text]', '#priceset');
  if (!inpTxt.length) { return; }
  // find "Other Amount" radio button
  var rbO = $(":radio[value='0']", '#priceset');

  inpTxt.on('keyup', function() {
    if ($(this).val()) {
      $('input[type=radio]:checked', '#priceset').not(rbO).prop('checked', false).each(function() {
        calculateRadioLineItemValue(this);
      });
      // click event is needed to update style for other amounts
      rbO.not(':checked').click();
      calculateText(this);
    }
  });
  $('input[type=radio]', '#priceset').not(rbO).on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      inpTxt.val('').each(function() {
        calculateText(this);
      });
    }
  });
});
```